# Create react app with typescript - @ts-ignore not working

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I just init a fresh project with  CRA2 with typescript option (https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript#docsNav)

But i can't use ts-ignore on file when i write this on App.tsx

```
let a = 1
/* @ts-ignore */
a = '123'
```

After launch yarn start i got :

```
Type error: Type '"123"' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Thanks